# Microsoft Excel: Make GetPivotData() refer a pivot table using its name

Tags: microsoft-excel, pivot-table

Microsoft Excel names pivot tables and provides means to rename it - 'PivotTable Name'.

[image]

The Microsoft Excel function
`GETPIVOTDATA(data_field, pivot_table, [field1, item1], ...)`
has a parameter 'pivot_table' which is the upper left R1C1 address of a pivot table.

Is there a way to instruct `GETPIVOTTDATA()` to refer to the pivot table using 'PivotTable Name'?

Answer (score 1):

According to the documentation [here](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/getpivotdata-function-8c083b99-a922-4ca0-af5e-3af55960761f), `pivot_table` must be:

> A reference to any cell, range of cells, or named range of cells in a
> PivotTable. This information is used to determine which PivotTable
> contains the data that you want to retrieve.

So, the short answer to your question is "No".

However, you can [create a named range](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/create-a-named-range-in-excel-adee78ff-bcf0-4283-8c29-83304ca0c29d), pointing to the upper-left cell of the pivot table, that has the same or similar name to your pivot table, then refer to that named range in the formula.

Comment: Thanks.  This is workable.

Comment: why is it then names can be defined for Pivot tables when they cannot be referenced: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/rename-a-pivottable-or-pivotchart-f8b73921-3494-48e2-a271-ce6c5d371cf4